# Enforcing instantiation of object in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I got a very easy question here, but don't know in what direction to search...

I built a class that extends another class with an uninstantiated object. How do I make sure I dont forget to instantiate the object in the subclass? Here's what I mean:

```
public class Hitbox{
  .... 
}

public class Enemy{
  protected Hitbox hbox;  // edit: changed to protected
}

public class AngryLady extends Enemy{
  hbox = new Hitbox(10, 20);  // Must not forget this!
}
```

One way would be to always check `if (hbox!=null)` before using thishandle, but that feels silly. There has to be an easier way like with abstract classes, where already the compiler gives an error when a method from the abstract class has not been implemented.

Comment: Why not just put the initializer in the super class only?

Comment: Why not have `hbox = new Hitbox();` in the constructor of the parent class?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add arguments to the Hitbox Constructor call. Every Subclass of Enemy will have a different Hitbox and hence I'm initializing the Hitboxes in the respective sublcass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize your variable in the constructor of the parent class:

```
public abstract class Enemy{
    protected Hitbox hbox;
    public Enemy(int a, int b) {
        hbox = new Hitbox(a, b);
    }
}

public class AngryLady extends Enemy {
    public AngryLady(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
}
```

If you need a different `HitBox` instance per subclass of `Enemy`, use Factory method pattern. This is a very simple example:

```
public enum HitboxType {
    ANGRY
}

public final class HitboxFactory {
    private HitboxFactory() {
    }

    public static Hitbox createHitbox(HitboxType hitboxType) {
        switch(hitboxType) {
            case HitboxType.ANGRY:
                return new AngryHitbox();
            case <another_case>:
                return <respective hitbox>
        }
        //in case of invalid parameter
        return null;
    }
}
```

And it would be better using dependency injection:

```
public abstract class Enemy{
    protected Hitbox hbox;
    public Enemy(Hitbox hitbox) {
        hbox = hitbox;
    }
}

public class AngryLady extends Enemy {
    public AngryLady(Hitbox hitbox)) {
        super(hitbox);
    }
}

//...
AngryLady angryLady = new AngryLady(HitboxFactory.createHitbox(HitboxType.ANGRY));
//...
```

Another tip in case you don't want to have `null` `Hitbox`es is to create an empty `Hitbox`:

```
public class EmptyHitbox extends Hitbox {
    public EmptyHitbox() {
        super(0,0); //or whatever arguments it needs
    }
}
```

And in the factory method:

```
public static Hitbox createHitbox(HitboxType hitboxType) {
    switch(hitboxType) {
       /* ... */
    }
    //in case of invalid parameter
    return new EmptyHitbox();
}
```

Comment: @potAito another way using factory method and dependency injection to assure you have a hitbox.

Comment: Factories! Of course! That's perfect, I was going to implement it anyway. Then I can check once upon creation if everything is good. Thank you very much!

Comment: @potAito check the last edit to avoid having `null` values for your `Hitbox`

Answer (score 2):

First it should be `protected` since subclass doesn't have access to `private` fields.

```
public class Enemy{
  protected Hitbox hbox;
}
```

To make sure you don't forget, you should really initiate the object where you are declaring it - the parent class.

```
public class Enemy{
    //if you just don't want/need to define a constructor explicitly and you know a b ahead.
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    protected Hitbox hbox = new Hitbox(a, b); 
}
```

In this case, you can always use `hbox` in the subclass without worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `hbox` field is inherited from the parent class, it should be initialized at the parent class:

```
public class Enemy {
    private final static int DEFAULT_H = 10;
    private final static int DEFAULT_W = 10; 
    // default initialization 
    private HitBox hbox = new HitBox(DEFAULT_W,DEFAULT_H); 

    public HitBox getHBox() { 
       return hbox; 
    }
}
```

Unless `hbox` must be initialized differently for each subclass, in which case you should use chained constructors to initialize the `HitBox`.

```
public class Enemy {

    private final HitBox hbox; 

    public Enemy(HitBox hbox) {
        this.hbox= hbox; 
    }


    public HitBox getHBox() { 
       return this.hbox; 
    }
}


public class AngryLady extends Enemy{
   public AngryLady() {
        super(new HitBox(10, 20));
   }
}
```

This example assume `Enemy` is not an abstract class.